# Bitwise AND and : symbol

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I have been coding for almost two months now and I am just starting to get "fluent" with the basics of the language. Recently, I stumbled upon a piece of code that looked like so:

```
if (! (n & 1)) {
    median += a[n / 2 - 1];
    median /= 2;
}

map<int, int> f;

for (int e : a) {
    f[e]++;
}

int mode = 0;

for (auto e : f) {
    if (e.second > f[mode]) {
        mode = e.first;
    }
}
```

I understand that the first if uses the Bitwise operator but I can't seem to understand how it is being used there. I have read a couple of tutorials but they don't make much sense to me.

The second question I have regards the two for loops. They use the : symbol and have only one parameter? Isn't for supposed to have three?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical

Comment: I had been looking for an answer in cplusplus.com where they don't explain stuff the best way possible. Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic

Comment: If you got an answer which helps, accept it; or write your own answer if non of the given answers helped enough. Do not edit "SOLVED" into the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the bitwise AND it is checking if n is even. It works in the following way: if the last bit in n is a 1 (which it is for every odd number) the result of n & 1 will be 1, else it will be 0. Since anything != 0 is evaluated to true in c++ it is inverting this check. Since the entire expression is flipped by the "!" it will evalutate to false when n is odd and true when n is even.

As an example lets take n=3, n=4, n=5 and represent them in binary:

```
n=3:
0101 & 0001 = 0001

n=4:
1000 & 0001 = 0000

n=5:
1001 & 0001 = 0001
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/bitwise-and-operator-amp?view=vs-2017

For the range operation

```
for (int e : a)
```

it is

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is quite complicated, the Bitwise I mean, no?

Comment: It's a bit unintuative way to write it, the more common way would be to write it as (n % 2 == 0) as in "if n is evenly divisible by 2".

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did in this assignment. (It is a code the tutor of an online class gave us, but he told us that we wouldn't be learning these for a while, but I am not patient enough to wait :P).

Comment: @iaminsensible Not really that complicated; you just have two numbers represented in binary and compare each of their digits - if first digit is a 1 AND second digit is a 1 result is a 1, otherwise result is a 0. Same with OR except there the logic is; if first digit is a 1 OR second digit is a 1 result is a 1 otherwise it is a 0. XOR (eXclusive OR) is similar; if first or second digit (*only one of them*) is a 1 result is 1 otherwise result is 0.

Comment: Thank you. By the way, I read the cppreference documentation and if I understood correctly, if we have a loop: for(auto n : a) {...} (where a is an array with 5 elements) the body of the loop will be executed 5 times, or n times where n is equal to the number of array elements.

Answer (score 2):

[!(n & 1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)

Lay them out as a bitfields, example:

```
       101010101
     & 000000001
       ---------
result 000000001
```

The non-zero result value will in a boolean *true or false* context be promoted to `true`. Only the result `0` would be promoted to `false`. The `!` (*not*) reverses the result so that `true` becomes `false` and vise-a-versa.

The second question is about the [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
for (auto e : f) {
```

It's (since C++11) a simplified version of:

```
for(auto it=std::begin(f); it!=std::end(f); ++it) {
    auto e = *it;
```

Answer (score 0):

if n is even, converting it to binary will result in something like 1010, with the Least significant bit always being 0. 
If you & 0 and 1, you get 0.  The first if loop is to check if n is even.

For Bitwise operations -
 1. Convert number to binary.
 2. Perform operation on individual bit.
 e.g. 3&6 = 011&110 = 010 = 2